# Can the same TIN exist for both an SSN and an EIN?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ein, ssn

In the US, is it possible for the same 9 digits to exist as a valid SSN, and also as a valid EIN?

For example, *Person One* is 123-45-6789, and *Business Two, Inc* is 12-3456789.

Comment: Yes, it happens. I have no proof to show you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it can happen.

On Reddit’s r/personalfinance subreddit, a user posted their story about this happening to them:

[My SSN has the same integers as someone's EIN](https://www.reddit.com/r/personalfinance/comments/52ryaa/my_ssn_has_the_same_integers_as_someones_ein/)

A couple of people in the comments also claimed to have discovered this firsthand as well.